# Removing taxonomy query by pre_get_posts

Tags: pre-get-posts, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I would like to remove taxonomy related SQL query part from the main query. I am trying to use `pre_get_posts` `posts_where` filter.

An example of original not modified query WHERE part:

```
WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (800,801) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'service_photo' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'custom_meta_partner_subscription_level' )
```

My code:

```
function custom_loops($query) {
if (is_tax( 'service_photo_location' )){
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 20);
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'title');
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC');
    add_filter( 'posts_where', function ( $where ) {
        $where = preg_replace("(AND \( wp_term_relationships\.term_taxonomy_id IN \([0123456789,]*\) \))", "", $where);
        return $where;
    }, 10, 2 );
}
remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_loops' );
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_loops');
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there a streamlined, better solution to modify WHERE part or remove Taxonomy related part from the query? Using `preg_replace()` a bit dirty...
2. Although on `Regexpal` I have no problem with my pattern, when I place the expression into preg_replace it does NOT work.

Comment: What is the reason to remove the taxonomy arguments in the query for the taxonomy archive? It will stop being the taxonomy archive.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here. I don't get your logic here

Comment: It is a location taxonomy eg. "London". Posts has GPS coordinates and my aim is not only to list posts from London but posts around London. I use a GPS coordinates based distance calculation which modifies `post_in` query parameter. Surrounded posts has no taxonomy "London" that is why I would like to remove tax related query part. I know it would be easier to create it on a custom page with a custom query, but Taxonomy archive pages has several other advantage what I would keep and use. For example hierarchy, and built in methods to list all term pages, etc.. That is the reason. :)

Comment: you found any solution @user9909 ? I have similar situation now.